# Changing Printer Support File Path in Forge Design Automation API

Tags: autodesk-forge

In AutoCAD Design Automation API - How would one go about changing the Options --> Files (tab) --> Printer Support File Path --> Plot Style Table Search Path to point to another location during a work item execution? I have tried adjusting the RuntimeRequirements in the package contents xml file to point to my bundle contents, but that did not work.

```
<Components>
    <RuntimeRequirements
        OS="Win64"
        Platform="AutoCAD"
        SupportPath="./Contents/"/>
```

............

Any Suggestions? Ultimately im trying to upload a specific custom ctb file and plot with it
Thanks,
John

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to program to copy the related files from bundle to Plotter folders in your custom plugin dll.

Suppose you placed all the related files like .pmp,.pc3 and .ctb in Contents folder, as shown in pic

[image]

**Example:**

Then you need to run command, prior to running any PLOT commands. This will copy files to relevant folders when your execute workItem against the bundle package you have uploaded to DA service.

```
[CommandMethod("PlotLayoutCommands", "COPYPLOTTERFILES", CommandFlags.Modal)]
        public static void CopyPlotterFiles()
        {
            // Get the current document and database, and start a transaction            
            Document acDoc = Autodesk.AutoCAD.ApplicationServices.Core.Application.DocumentManager.MdiActiveDocument;
            Database acCurDb = acDoc.Database;
            //A way to copy files from bundle package to respective Printer Support Path
            object roamablePath = Autodesk.AutoCAD.ApplicationServices.Core.Application.GetSystemVariable("ROAMABLEROOTPREFIX");
            acDoc.Editor.WriteMessage("\nRoamable-Path\t:{0}\n", roamablePath.ToString());
            string pc3FileFound = HostApplicationServices.Current.FindFile("DAS-PDF.pc3", acCurDb, FindFileHint.Default);
            string pmpFileFound = HostApplicationServices.Current.FindFile("DAS-PDF.pmp", acCurDb, FindFileHint.Default);
            string plotStyleFileFound = HostApplicationServices.Current.FindFile("DAS-PDF.ctb", acCurDb, FindFileHint.Default);
            string scriptFileFound = HostApplicationServices.Current.FindFile("RunPlot.scr", acCurDb, FindFileHint.Default);
            
            acDoc.Editor.WriteMessage("\nPC3 Config\t:{0}\n", pc3FileFound);
            acDoc.Editor.WriteMessage("\nPMP File\t:{0}\n", pmpFileFound);
            acDoc.Editor.WriteMessage("\nCTB File\t:{0}\n", plotStyleFileFound);
            acDoc.Editor.WriteMessage("\nScript File\t:{0}\n", scriptFileFound);
            //Start Copying:
            string pmpFolder = "PMP Files";
            string pc3Folder = "Plotters";
            string plotStylesFolder = "Plot Styles";

            try
            {
                File.Copy(pc3FileFound,
                           Path.Combine(roamablePath.ToString(),
                            pc3Folder, Path.GetFileName(pc3FileFound)));
                File.Copy(pmpFileFound,
                            Path.Combine(roamablePath.ToString(),
                            pc3Folder, pmpFolder, Path.GetFileName(pmpFileFound)));
                File.Copy(plotStyleFileFound, Path.Combine(roamablePath.ToString(),
                            pc3Folder, plotStylesFolder, Path.GetFileName(plotStyleFileFound)));
                File.Copy(scriptFileFound, Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), Path.GetFileName(plotStyleFileFound)));
            }
            catch (System.Exception ex)
            {
                acDoc.Editor.WriteMessage("\n" + ex.Message);
            }

        }
```

or

You can create CustomPlot command something like this, which will set PC3 and CTB on the Layout.

```
public static void PlotLayout()
        {
            // Get the current document and database, and start a transaction            
            Document acDoc = Autodesk.AutoCAD.ApplicationServices.Core.Application.DocumentManager.MdiActiveDocument;
            Database acCurDb = acDoc.Database;
            //A way to copy files from bundle package to respective Printer Support Path
            object roamablePath = Autodesk.AutoCAD.ApplicationServices.Core.Application.GetSystemVariable("ROAMABLEROOTPREFIX");
            acDoc.Editor.WriteMessage("\nRoamable-Path\t:{0}\n", roamablePath.ToString());
            string pc3FileFound = HostApplicationServices.Current.FindFile("DAS-PDF.pc3", acCurDb, FindFileHint.Default);
            string pmpFileFound = HostApplicationServices.Current.FindFile("DAS-PDF.pmp", acCurDb, FindFileHint.Default);
            string plotStyleFileFound = HostApplicationServices.Current.FindFile("DAS-PDF.ctb", acCurDb, FindFileHint.Default);
            acDoc.Editor.WriteMessage("\nPC3 Config\t:{0}\n", pc3FileFound);
            acDoc.Editor.WriteMessage("\nPMP File\t:{0}\n", pmpFileFound);
            acDoc.Editor.WriteMessage("\nCTB File\t:{0}\n", plotStyleFileFound);
            //Start Copying:
            string pmpFolder = "PMP Files";
            string pc3Folder = "Plotters";
            string plotStylesFolder = "Plot Styles";

            try
            {
                File.Copy(pc3FileFound,
                           Path.Combine(roamablePath.ToString(),
                            pc3Folder, Path.GetFileName(pc3FileFound)),true);
                File.Copy(pmpFileFound,
                            Path.Combine(roamablePath.ToString(),
                            pc3Folder, pmpFolder, Path.GetFileName(pmpFileFound)), true);
                File.Copy(plotStyleFileFound, Path.Combine(roamablePath.ToString(),
                            pc3Folder, plotStylesFolder, Path.GetFileName(plotStyleFileFound)), true);
            }
            catch (System.Exception ex)
            {
                acDoc.Editor.WriteMessage("\n" + ex.Message);
            }
            // these prompts are only seen when running in interactive mode in autocad
            // when they are run from the activity, they are passed in as part of the script (like parameters)

            PromptResult result = acDoc.Editor.GetString("Enter PC3 File:");
            if (result.Status != PromptStatus.OK) return;
            string pc3FileName = result.StringResult;

            result = acDoc.Editor.GetString("Enter CTB File:");
            if (result.Status != PromptStatus.OK) return;
            string ctbFileName = result.StringResult;

            result = acDoc.Editor.GetString("Enter PDF Name :");
            if (result.Status != PromptStatus.OK) return;
            string pdfFileName = result.StringResult;

            using (Transaction acTrans = acCurDb.TransactionManager.StartTransaction())
            {
                // Reference the Layout Manager
                LayoutManager acLayoutMgr = LayoutManager.Current;



                // Get the current layout and output its name in the Command Line window
                Layout acLayout = acTrans.GetObject(acLayoutMgr.GetLayoutId(acLayoutMgr.CurrentLayout),
                                                    OpenMode.ForRead) as Layout;

                    
                    using (OpenCloseTransaction oct = new OpenCloseTransaction())
                    {
                        using (PlotSettingsValidator plotSetVal = PlotSettingsValidator.Current)
                        {
                            acDoc.Editor.WriteMessage($"\nStyle sheet of current layout:{acLayout.CurrentStyleSheet}");
                            if (!acLayout.IsWriteEnabled)
                            {
                                acLayout.UpgradeOpen();
                            }

                            plotSetVal.RefreshLists(acLayout);
                            if (plotSetVal.GetPlotStyleSheetList().Contains(ctbFileName))
                            {
                                if (acCurDb.PlotStyleMode)
                                {
                                    acDoc.Editor.WriteMessage($"\nThe plot style sheet is being set to {ctbFileName}");
                                    plotSetVal.SetCurrentStyleSheet(acLayout, ctbFileName);
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    acDoc.Editor.WriteMessage("\nUnable to set plot style in drawing using stb\n\n");
                                }

                            }
                        }                      
                        oct.Commit();
                    }


                
                
                PlotConfig acPlCfg = PlotConfigManager.SetCurrentConfig(pc3FileName);
                string mediaName = acPlCfg.Comment;
                // Get the PlotInfo from the layout
                using (PlotInfo acPlInfo = new PlotInfo())
                {
                    acPlInfo.Layout = acLayout.ObjectId;

                    // Get a copy of the PlotSettings from the layout
                    using (PlotSettings acPlSet = new PlotSettings(acLayout.ModelType))
                    {
                        acPlSet.CopyFrom(acLayout);


                        // Update the PlotSettings object
                        PlotSettingsValidator acPlSetVdr = PlotSettingsValidator.Current;

                        // Set the plot type
                        acPlSetVdr.SetPlotType(acPlSet, Autodesk.AutoCAD.DatabaseServices.PlotType.Extents);

                        // Set the plot scale
                        acPlSetVdr.SetUseStandardScale(acPlSet, true);
                        acPlSetVdr.SetStdScaleType(acPlSet, StdScaleType.ScaleToFit);

                        // Center the plot
                        acPlSetVdr.SetPlotCentered(acPlSet, true);

                        // Set the plot device to use
                        acPlSetVdr.SetPlotConfigurationName(acPlSet, Path.GetFileName(pc3FileName), acPlSet.CanonicalMediaName);

                        // Set the plot info as an override since it will
                        // not be saved back to the layout
                        acPlInfo.OverrideSettings = acPlSet;

                        // Validate the plot info
                        using (PlotInfoValidator acPlInfoVdr = new PlotInfoValidator())
                        {
                            acPlInfoVdr.MediaMatchingPolicy = MatchingPolicy.MatchEnabled;
                            acPlInfoVdr.Validate(acPlInfo);

                            // Check to see if a plot is already in progress
                            if (PlotFactory.ProcessPlotState == ProcessPlotState.NotPlotting)
                            {
                                using (PlotEngine acPlEng = PlotFactory.CreatePublishEngine())
                                {
                                    // Track the plot progress with a Progress dialog
                                    using (PlotProgressDialog acPlProgDlg = new PlotProgressDialog(false, 1, true))
                                    {
                                        using ((acPlProgDlg))
                                        {
                                            // Define the status messages to display 
                                            // when plotting starts
                                            acPlProgDlg.set_PlotMsgString(PlotMessageIndex.DialogTitle, "Plot Progress");
                                            acPlProgDlg.set_PlotMsgString(PlotMessageIndex.CancelJobButtonMessage, "Cancel Job");
                                            acPlProgDlg.set_PlotMsgString(PlotMessageIndex.CancelSheetButtonMessage, "Cancel Sheet");
                                            acPlProgDlg.set_PlotMsgString(PlotMessageIndex.SheetSetProgressCaption, "Sheet Set Progress");
                                            acPlProgDlg.set_PlotMsgString(PlotMessageIndex.SheetProgressCaption, "Sheet Progress");

                                            // Set the plot progress range
                                            acPlProgDlg.LowerPlotProgressRange = 0;
                                            acPlProgDlg.UpperPlotProgressRange = 100;
                                            acPlProgDlg.PlotProgressPos = 0;

                                            // Display the Progress dialog
                                            acPlProgDlg.OnBeginPlot();
                                            acPlProgDlg.IsVisible = true;

                                            // Start to plot the layout
                                            acPlEng.BeginPlot(acPlProgDlg, null);

                                            // Define the plot output
                                            acPlEng.BeginDocument(acPlInfo, acDoc.Name, null, 1, true, pdfFileName);

                                            // Display information about the current plot
                                            acPlProgDlg.set_PlotMsgString(PlotMessageIndex.Status, "Plotting: " + acDoc.Name + " - " + acLayout.LayoutName);

                                            // Set the sheet progress range
                                            acPlProgDlg.OnBeginSheet();
                                            acPlProgDlg.LowerSheetProgressRange = 0;
                                            acPlProgDlg.UpperSheetProgressRange = 100;
                                            acPlProgDlg.SheetProgressPos = 0;

                                            // Plot the first sheet/layout
                                            using (PlotPageInfo acPlPageInfo = new PlotPageInfo())
                                            {
                                                acPlEng.BeginPage(acPlPageInfo, acPlInfo, true, null);
                                            }

                                            acPlEng.BeginGenerateGraphics(null);
                                            acPlEng.EndGenerateGraphics(null);

                                            // Finish plotting the sheet/layout
                                            acPlEng.EndPage(null);
                                            acPlProgDlg.SheetProgressPos = 100;
                                            acPlProgDlg.OnEndSheet();

                                            // Finish plotting the document
                                            acPlEng.EndDocument(null);

                                            // Finish the plot
                                            acPlProgDlg.PlotProgressPos = 100;
                                            acPlProgDlg.OnEndPlot();
                                            acPlEng.EndPlot(null);
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Your Activity using C# .NET core.

```
 private async Task<string> SetupActivityAsync(string myApp)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Setting up activity...");
            var myActivity = $"{Owner}.{ActivityName}+{Label}";
            var actResponse = await this.api.ActivitiesApi.GetActivityAsync(myActivity, throwOnError: false);
            var activity = new Activity()
            {
                Appbundles = new List<string>()
                    {
                        myApp
                    },
                CommandLine = new List<string>()
                    {
                         $"$(engine.path)\\accoreconsole.exe /i $(args[inputFile].path) /al $(appbundles[{PackageName}].path) /s $(settings[script].path)"
                    },
                Engine = TargetEngine,
                Settings = new Dictionary<string, ISetting>()
                    {
                        { "script", new StringSetting() { Value = "CustomPlot\nDAS-PDF.pc3\nDAS-PDF.ctb\nresult.pdf\n" } }
                    },
                Parameters = new Dictionary<string, Parameter>()
                    {
                        { "inputFile", new Parameter() { Verb= Verb.Get, LocalName = "$(HostDwg)",  Required = true } },                       
                        { "outputFile", new Parameter() { Verb= Verb.Put,  LocalName = "result.pdf", Required= true} }
                    },
                Id = ActivityName
            };
            if (actResponse.HttpResponse.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.NotFound)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Creating activity {myActivity}...");
                await api.CreateActivityAsync(activity, Label);
                return myActivity;
            }
            await actResponse.HttpResponse.EnsureSuccessStatusCodeAsync();
            Console.WriteLine("\tFound existing activity...");
            if (!Equals(activity, actResponse.Content))
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"\tUpdating activity {myActivity}...");
                await api.UpdateActivityAsync(activity, Label);
            }
            return myActivity;            
        }
```

And, Workitem:

```
    var workItemStatus = await api.CreateWorkItemAsync(new Autodesk.Forge.DesignAutomation.Model.WorkItem()
    {
        ActivityId = myActivity,
        Arguments = new Dictionary<string, IArgument>() {
                      {
                       "inputFile",
                       new XrefTreeArgument() {
                        Url = DownloadUrl,
                        Verb = Verb.Get
                       }
                      }, {
                       "outputFile",
                       new XrefTreeArgument() {
                        Verb = Verb.Put, Url = UploadUrl
                       }
                      }
                     }
    });
```

Comment: Thankyou! - i was almost there just couldnt figure out how to copy the bundled ctb to the roaming folder location. Much appreciated - John